# In China, can competent government officials get rich legitimately?

Tags: china, public-sector-compensation

Under free market capitalism, people can get immensely rich legitimately.

Start-up founders can create businesses and make tons of money.

Good leaders can be CEOs and make a lot of money.

In China, how does this work?

I read that some very successful politicians, that oversee a growth of 20% per year in Shanghai, go to life time jail over $300k bribe. You kidding me? This guy oversees a very large economy and is doing only $300k?

That guy manage a $1 trillion economy and need to break the law to make $300k.

For comparison, Amazon.com is also a $1 trillion "economy". Jeff Bezos easily make $150 million dollar bonus **LEGALLY**.

I've heard Xi Jinping salary is a mere $28k.

Why so small?

https://qz.com/329584/does-chinese-president-xi-jinping-really-earn-just-22000-a-year/

Comment: I'm not a China specialist, but in USSR, the way this worked was, you didn't get big money. You got big perks that were far far more valuable than money (e.g., elite level medical care, dachas, prestige living location, elite schools, access to Western goods, preferential vacation spots, preferential access to higher education, immunity from cops e.g. for traffic violations, generally higher standard of living).

Comment: So your high standard of living is linked to your job. You can't just quit your job and still enjoy it?

Comment: A $300k **bribe** is not the same as a $300k **income**. In most capitalist countries too, you might be enjailed (not for a life-time sentence, sure) is you're convicted of having received a $300k bribe.

Comment: Can you add references for the things you *read* or *heard* (Xi's salary, for instance) ?

Comment: Yes. But that guy is governing economy worth $1 trillion dollar. A CEO managing a business that big would have at least gotten $150 million dollar easily.

Comment: @J.Chang - it was kind of... all interconnected. You didn't usually quit high level job to become a garbage person. And it tied into being high level Party functionary too.

Comment: You seem to assume that annual incomes of several millions of dollars are a natural thing. Just 20 years ago, even in the US, the highest-paid CEOs were probably making incomes one or two orders of magnitude less than Jeff Bezos' today. I suppose the real question would be how and why it has boomed so much in a period of salary moderation for middle-class workers, rather than why China doesn't follow that trend (or rather, why they follow it with a delay).

Comment: If I manage some trillions of dollars of economy and I earn $22k salary, I would steal. I think that's the reason why chinese don't want democracy. They want to steal money. As for economic growth. Any country embracing free market will grow

Comment: Earning millions of dollars is not natural. But if you are a head of an organization that manage trilions of dollars, then yes it make sense.

Comment: @J.Chang: What is "unnatural" about earning millions of dollars? Many, many people do. Earning millions of dollars *a year* is not normal, but still plenty of people do. What you earn is based on "labor"(with a broad definition of labor) is worth to other people. Entertainers (e.g. athletes, musicians, actors) can reach millions of dollars with a broad enough audience, as can those with specialized skills (e.g. doctors, lawyers, engineers).

Comment: Precisely. What about some good governor? They produces good value too right? How come their salary is only $22k?

Comment: Having a proof that someone stole 300k does not mean that he stole **only 300k**. Maybe there way bigger accusations which are way harder or impossible to proof. For example Al Capone was put in jail for tax evasion (it was very hard to prove that he was the mastermind of the crime empire).